# How to create a chatbot using a loop? (java)

Tags: java, loops, chatbot

I'm trying to create a chatbot using a loop that will have a conversation with the user, and will stop when the user types "bye". Kind of like what i'm trying to do here, except i suck at programming:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String question;

    System.out.println("Hello");

    do
    {
        question = sc.nextLine();

        if (question.equals("how are you");
        {
            System.out.println("good");
        }

        if (question.equals("bye"))
        {
            System.out.println("bye");
            break;
        }
    } while (!sc.nextLine().equals("bye"));
}
```

}

Comment: You should explain what is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should take your **"Bye"** out of the loop. So if `sc.nextLine().equals("bye")` it finishes the loop, say **"bye"** and finishes the program.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    String question;

    System.out.println("Hello");

    do
    {
        question = sc.nextLine();

        if (question.equals("how are you");
        {
            System.out.println("good");
        }

    } while (!question.equals("bye"));    

            System.out.println("bye");
```

Comment: that's not going to work correctly either because the while loop reads a line via nextLine, there should be just 1 `nextLine` per iteration, here are 2